# Google Calendar: Add-to-calendar link over SMS that doesn't require Google Sign In

Tags: google-calendar-api

I need to share a calendar event over SMS.

I made the calendar public.

I'm sharing the Publish Event link.

For users that are signed into Google on their default phone browser, this works. They click the link, it opens the event, and they can save to their calendar.

For users not signed in or that don't even have a Google account, they get stuck at the Google sign in page.

Any ideas on a solution for the second bucket of users?

Basically looking for the equivalent of sharing an ics file that can be saved to any calendar (I think).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the incorrect link. As you can see in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37083?hl=en&ref_topic=3417970) > `Share your public Calendar` section:

> You can share your calendar with a link so that others can get your calendar in a web browser, Google Calendar, or another application.
>
> 1. On your computer, open Google Calendar.
> 2. At the top right, click Settings [image: Settings] and then Settings.
> 3. Click the name of the calendar you want to share.
>
>    - If you want people to subscribe to your calendar, click Access
>        permissions and then Get shareable link.​
>    - **If you want a link that doesn't require people to sign in or subscribe**, click Integrate calendar and share the public link.

Comment: This is to share entire calendar though, correct? I'm only looking to share a specific event. Maybe I'm wrong there. Let me know. Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes, it's for Calendar. It's not possible to share a single event.